# What's the best way to iterate through documents on a Firestore collection summing values?

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to find out how to sum a value stored on every document inside a Firestore colletion, using the "cloud_firestore" package from Flutter.

I tried this code:

```
double queryValues() {
    total = 0.0;

    Firestore.instance
        .collection('myCollection')
        .snapshots()
        .listen((snapshot) {
        snapshot.documents.forEach((doc) => this.total += 
                                            doc.data['amount']);
    });
    debugPrint(this.total.toString());
    return total;
  }
```

But I end up printing 0.0 as result. If I remove the first line (total = 0.0.) I get the sum to work, but if I reload the values are doubling (adding up to the old total).

I known they say the best solution is to store this aggregated value using a Cloud Function on every document write, but that would be a pain as I want to make totals by some range periods available for the user to query (month, year, week). Those queries result on a small number of documents, so for me it would be ideal just to iterate over the resulting collection).

This is my first question posted and I really appreciate any thoughts on this.

Comment: `listen()` is asynchronous and returns immediately.  This means that your print statement runs before the database query has finished and the total is computed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using an async function either you do all your work inside the `listen()` method or wait outside it til you are sure everything has finished inside.

The "Flutter" way of handling the second case is using `setState()`. You `build()` the widget tree with the initial outside value and when the async function finishes you call `setState()` so the widget tree is rebuilt with the new value.

(As a side note, inside the async function you could use the `fold()` list method that accumulates on the previous operation).

Here is a complete simple app that would use the external total value:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      home: MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  double total = 0.0;

  @override
  initState() {
    super.initState();
    queryValues();
  }

  void queryValues() {
    Firestore.instance
        .collection('myCollection')
        .snapshots()
        .listen((snapshot) {
      double tempTotal = snapshot.documents.fold(0, (tot, doc) => tot + doc.data['amount']);
      setState(() {total = tempTotal;});
      debugPrint(total.toString());
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(child: Text("Total: $total")),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Hey chemamolins! Thanks alot for your time! I'm afraid this code might have the same async issue explained by Doug and Frank. Also, how can I use the total outside the listen context? (from the place I called queryValues())

Comment: You are right. I had misunderstood your question. I thought you had a problem calculating the total value. I have rewritten my answer with a typical flutter way of using the external total value.

Answer (score 5):

```
 CollectionReference _documentRef=Firestore.instance.collection("User");

   _documentRef.getDocuments().then((ds){
     if(ds!=null){
            ds.documents.forEach((value){
              print(value.data);
            });
     }
   });
```

Answer (score 1):

As Doug commented, data is loaded from Firestore asynchronously. By the time you print the sum, data hasn't loaded yet, the `forEach` hasn't run yet, and the total will still be `0.0`.

It's easiest to see what's happening by placing a few print statements:

```
print("Before calling listen");
Firestore.instance
    .collection('myCollection')
    .snapshots()
    .documents((snapshot) {
      print("Got data");
    }
print("After calling listen");
```

When you run this code, it prints:

> Before calling listen
>
> After calling listen
>
> Got data

This is probably not the order you expected. But it explains why you get no result and a sum of `0.0`: the data hasn't loaded yet.

To solve this you need to use Dart's `async`/`await` keywords.

```
double queryValues() async {
  total = 0.0;

  docs = await Firestore.instance
    .collection('myCollection')
    .snapshots()
    .documents((snapshot);
  docs.forEach((doc) => this.total += doc.data['amount']));
  debugPrint(this.total.toString());
  return total;
}
```

You'll notice I also replaced `listen()` with `get()`, since you only want to get the documents once (a `listen()` will stay active, which means you can't return a result).

And then call it with:

```
sum = await queryValues();
print(sum)
```

Comment: I really appreciate the lesson Frank! I must study more about the async world out there! But regarding the code there are still some issues: [dart] The method 'get' isn't defined for the class 'Stream<QuerySnapshot>'.

Comment: @DanteFilho instead of .get(..) here please try .documents(). That should return the list of documents that matches the query (in this case with no qualifiers). Once you have to documents in the docs variable you should be able to use the .forEach as puf has done.

Comment: @ArthurThompson there's no .documents() also.  I'll keep the .listen() as the graphs I'm doing would keep getting updated that way.

Comment: There is no way to await a listener, since it doesn't have a clear completion moment.