# Flutter Firestore - The method 'documents' isn't defined for the type 'Stream'

Tags: flutter, asynchronous, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to iterate through collections within a document (using a for loop) and to get and capture data from each of those collections documents. When I first attempted this I used a stream to listen for the data, but the function would always return an empty array due to the async function.

My Code

```
for (final day in daysRunOn) {
  databaseReference
      .collection('users')
      .document(user.uid)
      .collection(day)
      .snapshots()
      .documents((snapshot) {

      });

}
```

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52729497/whats-the-best-way-to-iterate-through-documents-on-a-firestore-collection-summi) suggests I should not use a stream so I removed it. I am trying to now run this but I keep getting an error on the .documents part which says "The method 'documents' isn't defined for the type 'Stream'."  but I don't understand how or why this is still a stream.

Suggested method from stack overflow

```
double queryValues() async {
  total = 0.0;

  docs = await Firestore.instance
      .collection('myCollection')
      .snapshots()
      .documents((snapshot);
   docs.forEach((doc) => this.total += doc.data['amount']));
   debugPrint(this.total.toString());
   return total;
  }
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
getDocs() async { 
  total = 0.0;

  snapshot = await Firestore.instance
      .collection('myCollection')
      .snapshots();

  docs = snapshot.data.documents;
  docs.forEach((doc) => this.total += doc.data['amount']));
  debugPrint(this.total.toString());
  return total;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this code

```
    List<String> daysRunOn = ['day1','day2','...'];
    int x = 0;
    double total = 0.0;

    Future<double> getTotal() async {
     if(x == 0) total = 0.0;
     var querySnapshot = await 
       Firestore.instance.collection('users/${user.uid}/${daysRunOn[x]}').getDocuments();
     querySnapshot.documents.forEach((doc) => total += doc.data['amount']);
     if(x == daysRunOn.length-1){
       //  the loop has finished
       x = 0;
       debugPrint(total.toString());
       return total;
     } else {
       x++;
       return getTotal();
     }
   }
```